# Python ctypes, dll function arguments

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a DLL with a function

```
EXPORT long Util_funct( char *intext, char *outtext, int *outlen )
```

Looks like it expects char *intext, char *outtext, int *outlen.
I wass trying to define differnt data types in python so i can pass an argument, but no success so far.

```
from ctypes import *

string1 = "testrr"
#b_string1 = string1.encode('utf-8')

dll = WinDLL('util.dll')
funct = dll.Util_funct

funct.argtypes = [c_wchar_p,c_char_p, POINTER(c_int)]
funct.restype = c_char_p

p = c_int()
buf = create_string_buffer(1024)
retval = funct(string1, buf, byref(p))

print(retval)
```

The output is None, but I see some changes in `p`.
Could you please help me to define proper data types for the function.

Comment: The return type (`restype`) is `c_long`, not `c_char_p`.

Comment: You may also need to use `string1 = create_string_buffer('testrr')` instead of `string1 = 'testrr'` if your function is expecting a mutable buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from ctypes import *

string1 = b'testrr'     # byte string for char*

dll = CDLL('util.dll')  # CDLL unless function declared __stdcall
funct = dll.Util_funct

funct.argtypes = c_char_p,c_char_p,POINTER(c_int) # c_char_p for char*
funct.restype = c_long # return value is long

p = c_int()
buf = create_string_buffer(1024) # assume this is big enough???
retval = funct(string1, buf, byref(p))

print(retval)
```

Comment: Thanks! This returns 0. Meanwhile i found usage in C# for this function if that will help to define proper data types ` [DllImport(@"utill.dll")]
        public static extern Util_func(byte[] clearText, byte[] encodedText, ref int l);` My iunderstanding is that the firts part is the input, the second is a bufer and the third kind of pointer, the function receives a string and should return encoded string . Please let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @user11098401 It makes sense.  Look at `buf.value` and `p.value` to see the returned string and length.

Comment: from **p.value**  i got 6 and it changes if i change **string1**, corresponds to the number of the characters. from **buf.value** i got **b'\x9d\xf93\x8d5\x90'** which also depends on  **string1**. Not sure how to get string on the output?

Comment: @user110988401 it looks like the function encrypts the input string in some way, so that looks right as well. The function takes byte strings. The “answer” you provided is wrong. `c_wchar_p` is the wrong type for the function input.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all your answers!
I think i figured it out. Using not the smartest way but just trying/experimenting with different data types.
As this is not a common library and i had no information for it, maybe the sulution wont be very useful for others , but anyway.

Looks like the function process only one character at a time, because if i pass a word it returns only one encoded character.
So here it is :

```
from ctypes import *


buf = create_unicode_buffer(1024)
string1 = "a"
c_s = c_wchar_p(string1)

dll = CDLL('util.dll')
enc = dll.Util_funct

enc.argtypes = c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p, POINTER(c_int)

enc.restype = c_long # i don't think this type matters at all

p = c_int()


enc(c_s, buf, byref(p))


print(p.value)
print(buf.value)
```

the output is 1 and the simbol ^

Thanks again

Comment: You’re getting one character because `c_wchar_p` is the wrong type.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I was with impression that c_wchar is single char, c_wchar_p is string.

Comment: No, `c_wchar` is a single wide character, which depending on the C compiler is 16 or 32 bits wide.  C equivalent is `wchar_t`.  `c_wchar_p` is a wide character strings (C `wchar_t*`).  For your C function with `char*` inputs you want `c_char_p`, which is a Python **byte** string.  `b'abcd'` for example.